# Cordova Speech Recognition Hangs in Android on Background Mode

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

We are integrating speech to text Voice Bot conversion. To convert user speech input to text, we are using speech recognition Cordova plugin https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin. It is working as expected when user start speaking on clicking 'mic' button, speech to text conversion is displayed in the UI.

Issue happen If I am in Voice Bot Screen and minimize the app, so app will be moved to background right. If again moved to foreground and if we click 'mic' button. It hangs and we are not getting any speech output. Need to kill the app and launch again in order to use Speech to text conversion.

Note: This issue is happening only on Android Device. IOS is working Fine.Also  We are using Angular 6, Cordova 7

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. It's related to Android Device. we test the same in another device. It's working as expected.